# When using python to call chrome, selenium is 4.11.2. An error is reported

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I need help, the error code is as follows:

```
Stacktrace:
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6BB593BE2+58386]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6BB4F8EA2]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6BB39E0FB]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6BB3DEA2C]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6BB3DEBAC]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6BB419DB7]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6BB3FF01F]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6BB417D32]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6BB3FEDB3]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6BB3D3BC1]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6BB3D4E04]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6BB947F92+3942338]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6BB987500+4201776]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6BB97FF3F+4171631]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6BB6577B6+860134]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6BB503D38]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6BB4FF8E4]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6BB4FFA12]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6BB4F01E8]
BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF878687614+20]
RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF87A1426B1+33]

All PDFs downloaded.
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 203, in _new_conn
sock = connection.create_connection(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
raise err
File "D:\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Could not connect because the target computer actively     refused。

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
response = self._make_request(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 496, in _make_request
conn.request(
File "D:\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 395, in request
self.endheaders()
File "C:\Users\wayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 1281, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "C:\Users\wayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 1041, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "C:\Users\wayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 979, in send
self.connect()
File "D:\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 243, in connect
self.sock = self._new_conn()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 218, in _new_conn
raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001FCB5F3B790>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Could not connect because the target computer actively refused。

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\pythonProject\AI\AI1.py", line 63, in 
search_results = driver.page_source
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 446, in page_source
return self.execute(Command.GET_PAGE_SOURCE)["value"]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 343, in execute
response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 291, in execute
return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 312, in _request
response = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3_request_methods.py", line 110, in request
return self.request_encode_url(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3_request_methods.py", line 143, in request_encode_url
return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 443, in urlopen
response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 874, in urlopen
return self.urlopen(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 874, in urlopen
return self.urlopen(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 874, in urlopen
return self.urlopen(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
retries = retries.increment(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 515, in increment
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=53520): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/64878dc20247a847939dade692c4bb8d/source (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001FCB5F3B790>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061]

## Define the number of download retries

```
MAX_RETRIES = 3
```

## Define timeout (in seconds)

```
TIMEOUT = 60
```

I reinstalled chrome beta 117.0.5938.11 and chromedriver 117.0.5938.11. At the same time, there is an official version 116.0.5845.97 on the computer.